# Crear diseño y efecto agua en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo que crear el diseño del agua que está casi en el pie de la ventana (foto) y pensaba hacer un efecto con movimiento.... Alguna ayuda para guiarme a cómo hacerlo?[image]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola hace poco hice algo similar, y me guié de la publicación de una esta [página](https://medium.com/@nhancv/flutter-wave-clipper-animation-dc2017ddfcf3), el diseño al final te quedaría algo así:

```
child: new ClipPath(
        child: new Container(
          width: widget.screenSize.width,
          height: 200.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        clipper: new WaveClipper(time.value, sinWave),
      ),
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Lo veo muy redundante publicar el código que esta en la página.

Comment: Okey, gracias .